# Determining Distance between two objects known in Size and distance of one object

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a 10 Cent in my Hand (Diameter 19,2mm) and a DIN-A4 Paper on the table (297mm) I am holding the coin in front of my eye so that it fills the Paper, and i am using the following formula:

x = distance to Paper

diameterCoin = 19,2mm

distanceEyeToCoin = 19,2mm * 7

diameterPaper = 297mm

> Formula: diamterCoin / distanceEyeToCoin = diameterPaper / x
>
> Formula': (diamterCoin / distanceEyeToCoin) * diameterPaper = x

(19,2 / (7 * 19,2) ) * 297 = 42mm which is not right as i am standing at least 2m far from the object

P.S.: Math is my weakness

Comment: where does the 19,2mm * 7 distanceEyeToCoin come from? Why not just give the distance?  More importantly, why do you give 2 formulae for computing the final result?